# Use two foreach loop return wrong

Tags: php

```
 <?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
    $getAlbumCusId = getAlbumCusId($id); //first function to get siteIds from first table from first database    
    foreach ($getAlbumCusId as $AlCusId) {
        $proId = $AlCusId['siteid']; // got siteIds, return 2 items

        $viewinv = viewinv($proId); // second function to get prices from first table from second database
        foreach ($viewinv as $vinv) {
            echo $vinv['price']; // but return 11 items
        }
    }
    ?>
```

first `function` return `siteid` from first `table` from first `db` and return two items, it's right, but now i want to get `price` from second `function` in first `table` in second `db` but it return 11 items! but i want to get `price` value for that two items from the first function, i know i did something wrong but i'm new in `php` no idea how to fix this.

**GOAL:** i got two items (from first function) i just want to get price for these two items.

**UPDATE:** problem solved;

Comment: you can have one query to get the ids with the price

Comment: yes, i also tried to JOIN two db but no success, i'm still learning php. @Chinito

Comment: then you have to learn mysql join first. that's the best to do it.

Comment: @Chinito i learning both in a same time, i tried but it was little confusing, because first function use a query that join two table from db1 and second function a query for db2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, in second table, you have many prices of the same item (in different times), so you should order prices by date DESC and limit the result to 1 to get the last price.

Comment: no i'm sure there is just one price for each siteid.

Comment: Can you past the query used to fetch prices?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your query is perfect which you are using to fetch the data in second function
`select price from second_table where proid = '$proid'`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are contacting the database name to the table like (db1.tablename, db2.tablename) otherwise if the same table exists in first database ie db1 it fetch the results from db1.tablename instead of db2.tablename